# Do we have a procedure for recommending good sources, or a place where we can store the links to these references?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

The reason I am asking is that this article by Lazzlo Bock, the HR for Google, on how (not) to write a resume just appeared on LinkedIn: [The Biggest Mistakes I See on Resumes and How to Correct Them](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/article/20140917045901-24454816-the-5-biggest-mistakes-i-see-on-resumes-and-how-to-correct-them)

Lazzlo Bock is planning to write a couple more articles.

I believe that the advice he gives would be helpful to all of us - I also like that he goes into the rationale for his advice - including the experienced ones :)

Answer (score 6):

Another option too could be a more canonical question, even if you asked it, to have a duplicate/reference for other questions. I've asked a few questions purely for the "this question keeps coming up in related fashions and yet there's not a good duplicate or related question" reason.

Many of my questions are like that and I know several other active users have some too. I'm sure I'm missing some on this list, but here are some:

- [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/896/2322)
- [What is a relieving letter? What are the consequences of not having one?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20945/2322)
- [How can I prepare for getting hit by a bus?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9128/2322)
- [How can I approach career development with a boss who doesn't seem to support this?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11197/2322) (see the bounty text at bottom of question)
- [To what extent do attributes making a resume "good" generalize across industries?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/7355/2322)
- [Why is it important to gain "visibility" in the workplace?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11816/2322) (this had a lengthy chat discussion before it was posted about this idea)

Comment: I am learning something new today, so it's a good day :)

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan the "career dev with boss not supporting" question is one I very deliberately asked because for a while, and still, we got SO MANY questions which basically boiled down to "my boss won't help me advance my career" and the core problem in all of them was what I asked.

Comment: It can also be fun to make these questions because it helps feel like we as a community are taking ownership of helping people. YMMV here, I find it pretty fulfilling.

Answer (score 5):

We absolutely have such a place: **['resume' tag wiki](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/resume/info)**.

Procedure for this has been introduced in Stack Exchange blog article: [Redesigned Tags Page](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/).

Best practices for how to fill it can be found at Meta Stack Exchange, in posts tagged... not surprisingly, [tag-wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69584/165773), for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69585/165773) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49723/165773).

For a really inspiring example of how it can be done well, refer ['scala' tag wiki at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) - few hundreds useful references, carefully picked, structured for comfortable use and study, maintained with [great love and care](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607000/revisions).

Comment: The 'scala' tag is indeed impressive :)